# How to print the previous word if the condition is met?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
a=[
helloworld:
prodValue:
version:7
class:[
ratio:
value: ""
stackOverflow:
version:3
]
#Inspect Output
"helloworld:"
"prodValue:"
"version:7"    
"class:["
"ratio:"
"value: """
"stackOverflow:"
"version:3"
```

I want to print the previous word if the next word is version. Is there any ruby method to split the previous word if it detects some string ? I am using the following ruby script

`a.delete("\n").delete(":").gsub(/\s+/,'').split('version:',-1)`

Comment: `key = curr_line.gsub(/\s+/,'').delete("\n").split('version:')`

Answer (score 1):

remember the previous line and only output if it matches your criteria.

```
previous_line = ""
File.foreach(input_file) do |line|
   puts previous_line if line.include? 'version:'
   previous_line = line
end
```

To store this in an array:

```
previous_line = ""
detected_vals = []
File.foreach(input_file) do |line|
   detected_vals << previous_line if line.include? 'version:'
   previous_line = line
end
puts detected_vals.inspect
```

Comment: I tried this logic & it seems working fine but I have to store these values into array. So when I am pushing these values into array, it stores weird values. Could you please suggest any string manipulation method?

Comment: @ChintanVadgama define "weird" values.  Also -- it would be better to ask your question completely in the question block at the top.  Context related to comments is often lost.

Comment: @Mircea I have revised my question. I will tackle this problem in a different way. Could you pls. help me with the above question ?